# Could not dial on my galaxy tab

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, phone-app

How to get Dialer application on my T-Mobile Galaxy tab?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the only way to get dialer is to reinstall the european firmware: http://www.thegalaxytabforum.com/index.php?/topic/151-gt-phone-dialer/

BTW, you are on the wrong site. SO is for specific programmers questions.

Comment: Thanks ... BTW, I hope that this question would not mess up stackoverflow ...

Comment: Awesome, going to check out that link now. thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

On your galaxy Tab goto

```
Application>Contacts
```

Now select Dialer tab

Comment: My Galaxy tab doesn't have Dailer tab ... When I wrote down the number on Memo and press on this number the message came "Dialer is not supported on this device."

Comment: I am not sure about T-mobile might be they have locked the device if that so you cant use dialer app unless you root your tablet